# Git Clone me está clonando un repositorio que no es, y Git push me lo está subiendo a ese otro repositorio que no me interesa

Tags: git, git-push, git-clone

Intentaré ser breve, el error lo tengo en un ordenador, en los otros donde he probado a hacer lo mismo no. Cuando hago una nueva carpeta, copio la ruta, y dentro clono un repositorio que tengo en github, lo que me está clonando es **otro** repositorio que tengo, y a la hora de hacer un git push me lo está subiendo a los 2 repositorios, subiendo los archivos al primer repositorio que no me interesa, y dándome error en el que sí me interesa. Las rutas están todas bien copiadas, y estoy en las carpetas correctas.

He hecho un git remote -v para ver las conexiones remotas de mis repositorios, y me llevo la sorpresa de que el repositorio que no me interesa que esté, aparece siempre ahí como por default, es decir esa conexión siempre la tengo activa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis estoy en la ruta de mi carpeta donde tengo el repositorio clonado VVariablesPHP, hago un git push origin main y lo que intenta es subirlo a otro repositorio (y lo consigue), y luego a VVariablesPHP que es donde me interesa, salta ese error.

He seguido las sugerencias del mensaje amarillo pero el error persiste, he intentado crear otros repositorios y más de lo mismo. ¿Se os ocurre que puede causar esto?

Un saludo.

Comment: Y cómo hiciste el git clone del repo? De verdad, de verdad es poco probable que github se equivoque o que el repo te diga algo diferente... entonces, es importante ver desde el comienzo. Sobre todo si git remote -v dice lo que dice. Por favor, pon la salida de los comandos como texto en lo posible, con eso no nos resumes el contenido sino que vemos qué dice (así como con la imagen, censura o modifica lo que consideres)

Comment: La verdad es que no me suena ni un poquito que en un solo `push`, git vaya a tratar de empujar en 2 remotos diferentes. Solo por curiosidad, podrias incluir en la pregunta el contenido de `.git/config`? Cambia el valor de los usuarios en los URLs de los remotos, si necesitas. Y no lo subas como imagen sino como texto, plis.

Comment: @Alfabravo Mañana mismo recreo desde que hago el git clone, todos los pasos y subo capturas, pero básicamente, creo una carpeta nueva, en ella hago el git clone del repositorio que quiero, y da igual que repositorio sea, siempre me clona el mismo repo ProyectosPHP, he hecho un git config --list y siempre me aparece la conexión de ese repo activa como remote.origin.url=https://github.com/*********/ProyectosPHP

Comment: No subas capturas. Copia y pega el contenido del terminal _como texto_.

Comment: @eftshift0 Creo que es lo que le he contestado al compañero, hay un remoto que es el remote.origin.url=github.com*********/ProyectosPHP que está siempre activo, si consigo quitarlo de alguna forma quizás soluciono mi problema. Mañana mismo recreo todo el problema desde el inicio. Perdonad que no pueda ahora, no tengo ese ordenador donde está el fallo.

Comment: Es que me parece muy raro que en un solo push git vaya a tratar de subir a dos repoitorios, por eso pienso que debe haber algo raro en el `.git/config` y por eso creo que es mejor si lo colocas, así sea con valores editados.

Comment: Solucionado. La solución al problema, git config --global --edit y ahí me salía una url remota origin al repositorio que siempre me clonaba, no sé como pudo llegar ahí, lo he eliminado manualmente, y listo. Si queréis tengo toda la info en texto para reproducir el error, puedo actualizar el tema con su solución por si ayuda a alguien.